# How to compute rolling covariance more efficiently

Tags: r, covariance, rollapply

I am trying to compute a rolling covariance between a set of data (each column of my x variable) and one other (y variable) in R. I thought I could use one of the apply functions, but can not find how to roll two set of inputs at the same time. Here is what I tried :

```
 set.seed(1)
 x<-matrix(rnorm(500),nrow=100,ncol=5)
 y<-rnorm(100)
 rollapply(x,width=5,FUN= function(x) {cov(x,y)})
 z<-cbind(x,y)
 rollapply(z,width=5, FUN=function(x){cov(z,z[,6])})
```

But none is doing what I would like. One solution I found is to use a *for* loop, but wondering if I can be more efficient in R than :

```
dResult<-matrix(nrow=96,ncol=5)
for(iLine in 1:96){
    for(iCol in 1:5){
        dResult[iLine,iCol]=cov(x[iLine:(iLine+4),iCol],y[iLine:(iLine+4)])
    }
}
```

which gives me the expected result :

```
head(dResult)


           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  0.32056460 0.05281386 -1.13283586 -0.01741274 -0.01464430
[2,] -0.03246014 0.78631603 -0.34309778  0.29919297 -0.22243572
[3,] -0.16239479 0.56372428 -0.27476604  0.39007645  0.05461355
[4,] -0.56764687 0.09847672  0.11204244  0.78044096 -0.01980684
[5,] -0.43081539 0.01904417  0.01282632  0.35550327  0.31062580
[6,] -0.28890607 0.03967327  0.58307743  0.15055881  0.60704533
```

Comment: Nice job on a thorough first post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
x<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(500),nrow=100,ncol=5))
y<-rnorm(100)

library(zoo)

covResult = sapply(x,function(alpha) {

cov_value = rollapply(cbind(alpha,y),width=5,FUN = function(beta) cov(beta[,1],beta[,2]),by.column=FALSE,align="right") 

return(cov_value)

})

head(covResult)
#              V1         V2          V3          V4          V5
#[1,]  0.32056460 0.05281386 -1.13283586 -0.01741274 -0.01464430
#[2,] -0.03246014 0.78631603 -0.34309778  0.29919297 -0.22243572
#[3,] -0.16239479 0.56372428 -0.27476604  0.39007645  0.05461355
#[4,] -0.56764687 0.09847672  0.11204244  0.78044096 -0.01980684
#[5,] -0.43081539 0.01904417  0.01282632  0.35550327  0.31062580
#[6,] -0.28890607 0.03967327  0.58307743  0.15055881  0.60704533
```

Also check out:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
?chart.rollingCorrelation
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do in my second attempt with the _z_ variable, but my command of the _apply_ functions is still too limited. Thanks a lot !

Comment: If I was right in my comment to @Stibu , I guess this one should be also be faster than the _for_ loop I did

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution with `rollapply()` and `sapply()`:

```
sapply(1:5, function(j) rollapply(1:100, 5, function(i) cov(x[i, j], y[i])))
```

I think that it is more readable and more R-ish than the solution with for-loops, but I checked with `microbenchmark` and it seems to be slower.

Comment: Oh I see my error (my R is still busy) well done! +1

Comment: It is working indeed, thanks. I guess we are not gaining time as you are somehow creating two loops on indices here as well, not really _applying_ the _cov_ function to the x and y data directly, as you could maybe with _mapply_

Answer (score 3):

If you need something faster, and you do not need any of the non-default arguments to `cov`, you can use `TTR::runCov`. Note that it pads with leading `NA` by default.

The speed difference will matter more on larger data.  Here's an example of how to use it:

```
cov_joshua <- function() {
  apply(x, 2, function(x, y) TTR::runCov(x, y, 5), y = y)
}
```

And here's a comparison to the currently accepted answer using the small dataset the OP provided:

```
cov_osssan <- function() {
  f <- function(b) cov(b[,1], b[,2])
  apply(x, 2, function(a) {
    rollapplyr(cbind(a,y), width=5, FUN = f, by.column=FALSE)
  })
}
require(zoo)  # for cov_osssan
require(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
nr <- 100
nc <- 5
x <- matrix(rnorm(nc*nr),nrow=nr,ncol=nc)
y <- rnorm(nr)
microbenchmark(cov_osssan(), cov_joshua())
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#  cov_osssan() 22.881253 24.569906 25.625623 27.44348 32.81344   100
#  cov_joshua()  5.841422  6.170189  6.706466  7.47609 31.24717   100
all.equal(cov_osssan(), cov_joshua()[-(1:4),])  # rm leading NA
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, using a larger data set:

```
system.time(cov_joshua())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.117   0.032   2.158 
system.time(cov_osssan())
# ^C
# Timing stopped at: 144.957 0.36 145.491
```

I got tired of waiting (after ~2.5 minutes) for `cov_osssan` to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm running some long simulations, so cant use R, but reckon this should work it. The outer apply by columns will take the column, pass it to rollapply, where it will be used to do the rolling window covariance with y. Hopefully :D

```
apply(x,2,function(x) rollapply(x,width=5,function(z) cov(x,y)))
```

Comment: This does not work. You are always calculating the covariance of the complete vectors x and y inside `rollaply()`. Therefore, each column contains the same value repeated 96 times.